# Visual Studio, XML: Android:layout_weight not declared all of the sudden?

Tags: xml, visual-studio

I am doing layouts for a while now and I am pretty sure I know how to use weights, or gravity. But since as of today, VS cant seem to do anything with layout_weight or layout_gravity anymore. It gets a green underline and it says "attribute not declared":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#ffffff">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="100"
                android:background="#345543"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_profilepic_recview_chats"
                    android:background="@drawable/ripple"
                    android:src="@drawable/general_btn_magnefier"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="323"
                android:background="#123321"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#afebff" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

... Also, I have noticed that in xml files I built earlier where this worked, those attributes also get a green underline now.

Also, the designer now simply ignores all weights and therefore designing now becomes a  pain in the you know what.

Am I doing something wrong or is it VS that has a problem? And how would I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

... building and restarting the app and program seems to fix the issue. it still underlines the attributes but it now builds them in the designer ...